# Need help understanding this line of code?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Ive come across this line of code in an example, But I dont know what it does!

```
[(CTView*)self.view setAttString: attString];
```

`CTView` is a custom class of type `UIView` and this line of code is in the main view controller. I understand that the `setAttString:attString` is passing the string `attString` to a method in `CTView`, but im not sure what the first half of the line of code is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(CTView*)` reference is a "cast", a way of simply informing the compiler that you believe that `self.view`, which is technically defined as a `UIView`, is really a `CTView`, and therefore you want the compiler to permit the `setAttString` method without generating a warning.